# Is there a standard way to expand associations with Sails, Mongo and Waterline with .findOne()?

Tags: sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

My models contain associations to other models which are obviously just stored with their ObjectId. What I want to know is if there is a way to pass in the option to expand either all associations or a particular set of associations.

**So 'item model' looks like this (example):**

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },
    description:{
      type: 'string'
    },
    project: {
      model: 'project',
      required: true
    }, ...
```

**When you do:**

```
item.save(function(error, item) { ... })
```

It will auto expand all associations contained in 'item.' However, if you pass in this option it will not expand:

```
item.save({ populate: false }, function(error, item) { ... })
```

I'm wondering why 'save' would auto expand and I'm curious as to if there is a way to have 'findOne' also auto expand. I know you don't want to always expand because it can be hard on memory, but this could be useful to return the fully expanded object at certain times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to populate all associated models?

```
Model
    .findOne({name:''})
    .populateAll()
    .exec(
        function(error,result){}
    )
```

It will populate all associations. If you want to populate only one, you can go with

```
Model
    .findOne({name:''})
    .populate('project')
    .exec(
        function(error,result){}
    )
```

More. You can use 'select', 'where' & 'limit' in populate (works with Mongo)

```
Model
    .findOne({name:''})
    .populate('project',{
        {where: {field1: true}},
        {select: ['field1','field2']},
        limit: 3
    })
    .exec(
        function(error,result){}
    )
```

Of course you can populate few associations

```
Model
    .findOne({name:''})
    .populate('project')
    .populate('owner')
    .populate('othermodel')
    .exec(
        function(error,result){}
    )
```